# Windows user permissions mean that Epson 2 Scan Utility must be 'Run As Administrator'

Tags: windows-10, administrator, uac, scanner, epson-ecotank

I have a Windows 10 64-bit Dell laptop where the account I normally log into was set up by a company which no longer exists. The user name is "Administrator" and here are the details for that account as given by 'net user Administrator':

```
User name                    Administrator
Full Name
Comment                      Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
User's comment
Country/region code          000 (System Default)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            19/12/2018 18:54:34
Password expires             19/09/1984 12:26:18
Password changeable          19/12/2018 18:54:34
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   29/09/2020 13:53:09

Logon hours allowed          All

Local Group Memberships      *Administrators       *Users
Global Group memberships     *None
The command completed successfully.
```

On the face of it, this user account looks to have what could be loosely termed "admin privileges". But that's not actually the case for one specific area: an Epson printer which has a scanner.

I currently have a Epson ET-2600 with a built-in scanner. The whole of the printer is working just as you would expect it to - except that to set up the scanner and use it, I HAVE to run the Epson 2 Scan utility with "Run As Administrator" or else it simply doesn't function properly.

The weird thing is that this new printer replaces a much older Epson XP-305 which had EXACTLY the same issue (albeit in the case of the XP-305 I got round it by logging out of Administrator and logging into another account purely to be able to scan a document). When I replaced the printer, I was careful to properly uninstall every single item of Epson software, reboot, then install the new ET-2600 software.

I've been onto Epson Support of course, but their ability to help is limited to the functions of the hardware, not the software which drives it. It so happens we hit upon the workaround of "Run As Administrator" and, although that's not so terrible, it shouldn't have to be that way.

Clearly my Administrator user account has a missing or inappropriate permission which prevents me using the scanner without insisting on elevated privileges. Does anyone have any thoughts on what UAC configuration I might check and be able to try changing to see if I can avoid the need for "Run As Administrator" ? Needless to say, Epson just cannot be of any help (they don't give access to their development team !).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answers I see below are very smart.. BUT.. backup your stuff and reinstall windows clean.  This is not going to be the only problem you encounter.  For a scanner to require admin privs is inexcusable.  There is a time to reinstall and you have just encountered it.

Answer (score 0):

Normal administrators in windows 10 need to run all programs with run as administrator to get elevated priviliges, but built-in administrator account is the exception, that does not require Run as Administrator for elevation, in any UAC configuration. So, it might be a problem, run `sfc /scannow`, or try repair install.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer setup is weird: You seem to be using the built-in Administrator account,
but this account runs always in Admin mode and does not require using
"Run As Administrator". Yet you do need it.

So it seems that someone has renamed the real built-in Administrator account
([link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/rename-built-in-administrator-account-windows))
and created a new administrator account named "Administrator" and even set up
a misleading description for it. The real built-in Administrator account
has this description in Windows 10 :
"Built-in account for administering the computer/domain".

In addition, the scanner software is badly installed and evidently the permissions
on some registry items that it needs, or other components, require elevated
permissions so the scanner software can even access them. Just wonderful.

What I suggest:

- Take a good backup and also create a System Restore save, just in case
- Download the
  [Epson drivers for the EcoTank ET-2600](https://www.epson.eu/support?productID=20642&language=en#product_search),
  which is hopefully your printer (check it)
- Uninstall your printer software
- Install the Epson software (it might be enough to run the Epson Software Updater
  while the printer is turned on)
- Reboot and test
- If the problem still exists, get in touch with Epson Support,
  because this is their software after all
- If nothing works, you will need to live with the problem.